# DataServiceContext.Timeout Property Unit of Time

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services

I am trying to determine what is the unit of time for the ADO.Net Data Services timeout property. MSDN help doesn't identify it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.timeout.aspx

Can anyone confirm what the property value represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some testing it looks like the value determines the number of **seconds** before it will timeout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's ms. See my answer below.

Comment: I just retested my test application. The timeout value is definitely in seconds.

Comment: If you look at the disassembly (through Reflector) of DataServiceContext, you'll find it translates the Timeout value from seconds into milliseconds when it creates an HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The unit should be milliseconds (however @eyesnz has not found that to be correct). According to the [MSDN DataServiceContext.Timeout Property page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.timeout.aspx):

> This value is passed to the Timeout
>   property of the underlying
>   HttpWebRequest object. The value must
>   be set before executing any query or
>   update operations against the target
>   data service can affect the request.
>   The value may be changed between
>   requests to a data service and the new
>   value will be picked up by the next
>   data service request.

Referring to the [MSDN HtppWebRequest.Timeout Property page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx):

> The number of milliseconds to wait before the request times out. The default value is 100,000 milliseconds (100 seconds).

Comment: You are right about the documentation, but it is just not what I experience in practice. I am running VS2008 with .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: @eyesnz, strange. I'll leave this here to show what it is officially supposed to be, but your empirical tests supersede documentation...

Comment: The documentation fails to mention that DataServiceContext.Timeout is indeed in seconds; it does *translate* to the Timeout property of the HttpWebRequest (which is in milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

The unit is **seconds**. Documentation around this has been correctly updated for .Net 4 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.timeout.aspx